# supertest & mocha problems with integration tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, integration-testing, supertest

I am having a bad time trying to know what is going on here.

I'm setting some integration tests with mocha & supertest.

My problem is that the time showed on each "it" block is not reliable.

If I copy paste the same test, always, the first test takes like 5 times more. I know this must be something Im missing here, but can't understand why.

I know about require cache issue, but I don't think is related with my problem.

This is my test:

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var supertest = require( 'supertest' );
var should = require('should');


describe( 'dummy describe', function() {

  var app, request;

  beforeEach(function() {
    app = express();
    app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
      res.send( 'hey' );
    });
    request = supertest(app)
      .get('/')
      .set('User-Agent', 'my cool browser')
      .set('Accept', 'text/plain');
  });


  it( 'should do a dummy test', function( done ) {
    request
      .end( function( err, res ) {
        res.status.should.equal( 200 );
        res.text.should.equal( 'hey' );
        done();
    });
  });

  it( 'should do a dummy test', function( done ) {
    request
      .end( function( err, res ) {
        res.status.should.equal( 200 );
        res.text.should.equal( 'hey' );
        done();
    });
  });

});
```

Note that test is exactly the same.

This are my results:

[image]

Even more, if I add more tests (same test); I still get the same results:

[image]

I don't think this is a normal behaviour, since it don't give me a reliable metric.

So, question is **who is caching here ? or why is this happening ?**

Not sure if this issue is related with Mocha, supertest, node's http module, or what.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: My suspicion would be that creating a new Express app for each test may be the cause. Try moving that to a `before()` instead of `beforeEach()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that is not the issue. It is still happening. Anyway, to have express instantiated on a before each is also part of the testing (this will give us metrics about the app start-up time).

Comment: It's a bit of a puzzle. If you send a request to the Express app once before the tests, the first test is noticably faster. It's still slower than the following tests, but for me it drops to about 7-8ms from around 25ms.

Comment: Yeah, I see that too, but why is this happening ? I want to fully understand why this is happening. If not, I don't have full understanding of my tests. And thats a very bad thing. Plus, how can I rely on the metrics when they vary widely if its the first request ?

Comment: It looks like it's being caused by `supertest`, although I don't know why. I took Express out of the equation (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/4dc095052c1b1cbf71829af66408937a)) and the problem remains. When each test returns immediately, instead of calling `request.end()`, the runtime for each test is more or less the same (ruling out Mocha).

Comment: I checking supertest, and how it uses https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent  I can see a nocache plugin for it, but only requiring it its breaking my node environment...

Comment: I doubt that that plugin will fix anything, it simply sets some HTTP headers that your app isn't listening to anyway (and certainly not the "app" in my gist).

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right on that. Was checking their docs. now. Im quite sure somehow the request got cache somehow... Reading the src code now to see where it goes...

Comment: Im quite sure this is happening because of how http.get behaves: https://gist.github.com/Avcajaraville/aa5642aeac0ca5874cef3fe49e3b1e6c

Comment: It may also be `http.createServer()` that's causing the initial delay.

Comment: @robertklep how can that be ? The server object gets created and deleted on beforeEach / afterEach. I know that part is not showed on the original question, made some tests after. Could be that http object or something is caching something on the environment ? Im running out of ideas here ...

Comment: Never mind, I ruled out `http.createServer()` by having `http.get()` communicate with an external HTTP server. It looks like the first call to `http.get()` is slower than the rest.

Comment: Im quite sure at this point that the time we extra time on the first connection is due to establish socket connection. For overpass that, Im trying now to create and connect a socket, then re use it. But again, Im not being able to accomplish this. I created a different question for that, in case you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328024/how-to-manually-open-socket-and-use-it-with-http-request