# How to manually open socket and use it with http.request

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, mocha.js

Im writing some integration tests for a node project.

We need to get reliable metrics about server performance. For that, we want to open a socket between the server and the client before any test is performance, this way, we can eliminate the time needed to create a socket between client and server.

I have created a small test case like this:

```
'use strict';

var express = require( 'express' ),
    net     = require('net'),
    http    = require('http');

var host    = 'localhost',
    port    = 8000;

describe( 'dummy describe', function() {
  var app, server, agent, opts;
  before( function( done ) {
    app = express();
    app.get( '/', function( req, res, next ) {
      res.send( 'stuff' );
    });
    server = http.createServer( app );
    server.listen( 8000 );
    agent = new http.Agent({ maxSockets: 1 });
    agent.createConnection({ port: port, host: host }, function() {
      return net.createConnection({ port: port, host: host }, function() {
        console.log( 'Socket fd open on before block: ' + this._handle.fd );
        done();
      });
    });
    opts = {
      hostname: host,
      port: port,
      path: '/',
      agent: agent,
      method: 'GET',
    };
  });
  it( 'dummy test', function ( done ) {
    var req = http.request( opts, function( res ) {
      console.log( 'Socket fd used on GET: ' + res.socket._handle.fd );
      done();
    });
    req.end();
  });
});
```

Here, I can see the execution of the before block, where I console.log the socket file descriptor.

Reading node documentation, I figured out that his was the right way to pass a socket to a agent. But its not working, its output different sockets.

I tried a thousands combinations, but got no luck.

I want to manually connect to a socket, and then use it to perform http.request without having to re open a different socket.

What would be the correct way of doing this ?